# The meaning of the word "money" with different adjectives in context

Tags: meaning

Here is the context: "In cold, hard, merciless dollars, does it make sense to spend or borrow money on college?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning is figurative.  Usually, "cold, hard, merciless" is how we might describe someone who lacks empathy/emotions.  You'll find these in other similar expressions such as "cold hearted", "hard hearted" - which mean the same. Merciless means without mercy, unforgiving, ruthless.

When applied to something like money/dollars, it appears to be referring to the stark reality that money considerations are something which must be endured, as a fact of life without recourse to emotions, or something which is unavoidable however one may feel about it, without emotional attachment.

Comment: What does "in" mean there?

Comment: I would suggest it means something like "in terms of money".  For example, if you are visiting another country with a different currency, you could ask "How much is that in dollars?" - or If you buy a piece of cheese in a shop - "how much is that in money?" - as opposed to weight, etc.